# Dual Canadian/Polish citizenship, want to travel/visit to Poland frequently

Tags: canadian-citizens, polish-citizens

My dad has dual Canadian/Polish citizenship. He has been living in Canada for the past 37 years but would like to visit Poland on a regular basis, he now has an apartment there (left to him by his sister who died recently). He is currently collecting Canadian pension benefits (OAS and CPP).  Can he still collect his Canadian pension and be covered under the Ontario healthcare plan? Are there requirements for him to return to Canada to maintain benefits?  If so, how often must he return to Canada? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry for the incorrect question earlier, NEWBIE here.

Comment: Whatever passport he uses to travel makes no difference. The benefits question is surely dependent on his physical location, if anything, but that is off topic here and belongs on [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 1):

It makes absolutely no difference which citizenship he 'travels under', as the only difference is the passport he uses on the voyage.

Ontario health coverage applies only to those resident in Ontario. If your father moved to Poland he would lose coverage regardless of citizenship. Specifically the [residence requirements mean he must:](http://www.health.gov.on.ca/en/public/publications/ohip/short_absence.aspx)

- be physically present in Ontario for 153 days in any 12-month period;
- and be physically present in Ontario for at least 153 days of the first 183 days immediately after establishing residency in the province;
- and make your primary place of residence in Ontario.

Canadian pensions can be claimed regardless of citizenship or residence, though there may be some difference in the amount paid if you live abroad.